# Duplicating Stored Users C# MVC Linq

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

From my code below you can see I am getting the logged in users, username and then querying the database for any users with that username. If the is no user than I proceed to store that user in the database. 
The problem here is so far it seems only randomly I am getting a couple of people being stored twice. So far each of the ones that have been stored twice seem to be stored one after the next. What is it about my code that I am missing here? I don't get it this should be able to handle this and only store Users one time.

Adding more Detail: 
This site is running on two servers that are behind a load balancer. The database server is on a cluster. So I do not believe that Locking an object is an option here

```
            string username =  User.Identity.Name.Replace(@"MyDomain\", "");
            var user = db.UserBases.Where(x => x.UserName == username).Select(c => c.UserName).FirstOrDefault();
            string managerdistinguished = "";

            if(user == null)
            {
```

Comment: Maybe a fast f5 issue? if two queries for the same user come simultaneously when it does not exists then the user will be duplicated...

Comment: any thoughts on how to prevent that?

Comment: create an static object at the beginning of your class and surround the code with lock(theObject){...

Comment: @scripter78: If usernames need to be unique then I'd recommend adding a unique constraint on the username column in the database.  How are you storing these?  Are users submitting twice very quickly?

Comment: Are the duplicates with capital letters and with regular letters?

Comment: Either make the usernames unique (if applicable for your application) or add some sort of a unique identifier (hashed version of the username, possibly?) and check for the unique identifier instead

Comment: @David users shouldn't be refreshing or anything quickly but they are users and you never know what one of them will do. The Quicker I build a trap the quicker they are at finding a way of getting around it.

Comment: gusman do you have an example of that? I personally have never used lock before

Comment: at Mino the duplicates are like GBush and GBush (sorry for that being the example)

Comment: Also not suggesting my test was fool proof but I just tested the site, hit refresh like 10 times in a second. Not once did it duplicate my info.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this piece of code is part of a controller? So it seems this particular controller is sometimes called twice with the same bunch of data within a very short time. So during the first call, user is null and some DB-operation creates the user in the db. In the meantime the controller is called a second time with the same data. But as the insert is not complete yet, also this time the username will not be found, yet the user will be inserted twice.

Adding a unique constraint is only part of the deal. It will prohibit the second insertion, but also raise an error which you have to deal with.

In my opinion it is better to additionaly create a locking mechanism. While you check for and insert the new user, no other operation is allowed to access the userlist. The easiest way may be as Gusman suggested.

```
class MyController : Controller {

  //...
  private static object userlock = new object();
  //...

  ActionResult CheckUser() {

    string username =  User.Identity.Name.Replace(@"MyDomain\", "");

    lock(userlock) 
    {
      var user = db.UserBases.Where(x => x.UserName == username).Select(c => c.UserName).FirstOrDefault();

      if(user == null)
      {
        //insert user into db ...
      } //if (user ==null)

    } //lock (userlock)

    //...

  } //CheckUser()

}  //MyController
```

Make sure that you also put the lookup under the lock, so the next lookup may only happen after the insertion into the database is complete.

I'm not quite sure whether the `object userlock` has to be `static`, as I don't know if MVC creates a new instance of the controller for every request. If yes, `static` is needed, if no, `static` may not be needed (but doesn't harm either).

See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx

Comment: Lock prevents the issue on a single application server and will not work if there are two or more in a cluster. The database constraint is much more reliable.

Comment: I guess I should have stated that in my original question, although currently it is one app server one database here shortly it will be two app servers with a load balancer and a database cluster.